# MySQL PHP Query caching

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I have question that is driving me insane.
I'm building a web store, and obviously all the products have properties, in my case, something like "power", "color"... and my costumer wants the ability to search filter them by those properties. I tried those options:

- Adding a row for every property in the 'products' table
- Table properties(id, displayName) and productProperties(property, product, value)
- Storing the properties fields and values in a JSON field in the product table.

I've chosen the third option after trying them all, and here comes my question:

---

*Since all the queries I need to do are relative to the search result, is it possible to cache/store the result table and use it in the other queries?*

---

I'll explain: filtering the products means querying a table and selecting only the products that matches the filters, but then, I need to count the products in this subset (this is pretty easy to do with the last query) and get all the available properties that are present JUST in this subset of products. 
I could redo the filtering query every time, but it's inefficient, I already have asked the DBMS to do this query.

 Thanks for your help
Matteo

Comment: You can store the json in a session variable and then pull it to compare against subsequent data pulls

Comment: MYSQL will cache queries!

Comment: You would need to enable mysql query cache

Comment: Are there any specific steps or I can just follow a guide?

Comment: Your chosen solution was the wrong one.  You broke a rule of normalization and relational database design AND you now made it impossible to use the database to search/filter products by the property you want.  The right solution was to implement option 2.

Comment: As far as mysql is concerned there is query cache and then there is actual caching of the result. Innodb offers caching of the results.  Hopefully you are using InnoDB.

Comment: yes i did broke some normalization rule, but I'd like to inform you that  it is in fact possible, maybe it isn't extremely efficient, but searching inside a JSON object is possible and actually pretty fast in MySQL 5.7. In my ~2k lines table with about 3-4 properties to search from in the JSON field, i get around 200ms of page loading, including PHP and many other queries (the search is part of a subquery). If you want to check it out, digitalapi.me, it's in italian, but it's pretty straight forward (go to "prodotti" in the header)